# Switch collection in mongoengine for find query

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I've read mongoengine documentation about switching collection to save document. And test this code and it worked successfully:

```
from mongoengine.context_managers import switch_db

class Group(Document):
    name = StringField()

Group(name="test").save()  # Saves in the default db

with switch_collection(Group, 'group2000') as Group:
    Group(name="hello Group 2000 collection!").save()  # Saves in group2000 collection
```

But the problem is when I want to find saved document in switch collection `switch_collection` doesn't work at all.

```
with switch_collection(Group, 'group2000') as GroupT:
    GroupT.objects.get(name="hello Group 2000 collection!")  # Finds in group2000 collection
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the db you are querying that record from? 
GroupT.objects.using(dbname).filter(name="hello Group 2000 collection!")

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan It's same as the other collection.

Answer (score 9):

As of `mongoengine==0.10.0` `mongoengine.context_managers.switch_collection(cls, collection_name)`
used as "with switch_collection(Group, 'group1') as Group:" in the example
doesn't work inside functions. It gives `unboundlocalerror`. A simple get around with existing resources is :

To get:

```
new_group = Group.switch_collection(Group(),'group1')
from mongoengine.queryset import QuerySet
new_objects = QuerySet(Group,new_group._get_collection())
```

Use `new_objects.all()` to get all objects etc.

To save:

```
group_obj = Group()
group_obj.switch_collection('group2')
group_obj.save()
```

Comment: great, was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Although Prachetos Sadhukhan answer works for me, I prefer to get the collection directly, not relying on private _get_collection method:

```
from mongoengine import connection
new_group_collection = connection.get_db()['group1']
from mongoengine.queryset import QuerySet
new_objects = QuerySet(Group, new_group_collection)
```